# ndk compilation .so files and folders

Tags: android, android-ndk

I made a compilation and the result are 4 folders

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- x86

In other compilation my result is

- armv6
- armv7
- neon
- vfp

I need an .so for each folder, but Mips it´s for neon and x86 equals to vfp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neon is armv7 with NEON instructions support, not all armv7 devices support it.
All armv7 android devices support VFP, so you're safe using armv7 or vfp for armeabi-v7a.
armv6 is equivalent to Android armeabi.

x86 and mips are different architectures, you need a .so for these folders as well, but your other compilation doesn't seem to provide these out of the box ?